# Editing booleans from another class in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, boolean

This might be a nooby question, but I'm stuck.

What I have here is code in my form. This is the event I have assigned to my buttons.
These buttons are supposed to switch states of `booleans` in `SomeClass`.

Those booleans are all `public static bool boolA` etc.

Here is my form's code.

```
    public void switchButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button[] buttons = { btnA, btnB };
        bool[] bools = { SomeClass.boolA, SomeClass.boolB };

        Button button = (Button)sender;
        int index = Array.IndexOf(buttons, button);


        if (bools[index])
        {
            bools[index] = false;
            button.Text = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            bools[index] = true;
            button.Text = "Stop";
        }
    }
```

What happens is, the button's text gets set to "Stop" but never to "Start" when I click it again.

Help would very much be appriciated.

Comment: `if (boools[index])` is there an _o_ to much just in this code ?

Comment: `bools` is redefined everytime you click the button

Comment: @TripleEEE seems to be placeholder code based on the `class` names, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Liam that doesn't matter, as SomeClass.boolA, boolB are static fields

Comment: this'd all be a lot easier if you just didn't use the array. Why don't you just set `boolA` and `boolB` directly?

Comment: @TripleEEE Whoops. That was a typo from me. But that's not the problem.

Comment: @MadOX: It matters, because the array contains a *copy* of the values.

Comment: @Liam I have around 30 buttons and booleans. For the question I only showed 2 as an example.

Comment: the array still isn't helping. If you store each one in a static field, just update that field. The array is doing nothing but confusing you

Comment: @Liam I was hoping to make a compact method instead of a big if/switch statement.

Comment: @Tvde1 I'd rather build an method for this -  by the way, is this winforms or wpf - I guess it is winforms right?

Comment: @TripleEEE Yes, it is winforms. And my code is a method.

Comment: Why not check if(button.Text == "Start") instead?

Comment: @Carra That changes the button's text, yes. But not the `boolean` in `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bool` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx). They are atomic in .Net. So when you assign them to a new variable they are **copied**. So in:

```
bool[] bools = { SomeClass.boolA, SomeClass.boolB };
```

`bools[0]` lives in one memory address and `SomeClass.boolA` lives in a different one. There is no relation (unlike a reference type). Or to put it another way `bools[0] != SomeClass.boolA`. Changing `bools[0]` does not affect `SomeClass.boolA` and vice versa.

You can see this by running this code:

```
bool a = false;
bool[] bools = new bool[] {a};
bools[0] = true;

a == false; //true
bools[0] == true; //true
```

So you can't do what you want how you want to do it. Basically your going to have to manipulate the `SomeClass.boolA`, etc. independantly, probably using a `switch` or an `if`.

Comment: If you we're storing reference types what you are trying to do would work, FYI, but it won't for value types.